# Last value did not appear inside dynamic php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to rearrange the result that i get from db into new array which later will be use inside javascript. The problems here is when i rearrange the result data into new array, the last 2 line of the result is missing from array that i have created. I have tried many way but didn't found the solution.

result data from db:

```
[
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Gloss Art Card 250 gsm"},
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Gloss Art Card 310 gsm"},
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Gloss Art Card 360 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Briliant White 220 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Linen 240 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Metal Ice 250 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Synthetic Paper 180 micron"},
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Super White 250 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Suwen 240 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Vellum 220 gsm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Paper Material","specification":"Frosted Plastic Card 0.4mm"},
  {"attribute":"Type","specification":"Standard Business Card"}, 
  {"attribute":"Type","specification":"Folded Business Card"}, 
  {"attribute":"Type","specification":"Custom Die-Cut Business Card"}, 
  {"attribute":"Size","specification":"54mm x 89mm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Size","specification":"52mm x 86mm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Size","specification":"50mm x 89mm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Size","specification":"54mm x 86mm"}, 
  {"attribute":"Orientation","specification":"Portrait"}, 
  {"attribute":"Orientation","specification":"Landscape"}, 
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Not Required"}, 
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Matte 2 Side"}, 
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Matte 1 Side"}, 
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Gloss 2 Side"}, 
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Gloss 1 Side"}, 
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Gloss Water Based Varnish 2 Side"},
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Matte 2 Side + Spot UV 2 Side"},
  {"attribute":"Lamination","specification":"Matte 2 Side + Spot UV 1 Side"},
  {"attribute":"Hot Stamping","specification":"Not Required"}, 
  {"attribute":"Round Corner","specification":"Not Required"}, 
  {"attribute":"Hole Punching","specification":"Not Required"}, 
  {"attribute":"Color","specification":"4C 1 Side"}, 
  {"attribute":"Color","specification":"4C 2 Side"}]
```

Then rearrange the result data into new dynamic array:

```
    $attrArray = array(); //temp attr array as key data for data array
    $specArray = array(); //temp spec array as value data for data array
    $dataArray = array(); //array that consist key:[value] pair after rearrange data complete

    //check result data from db length
    for($x = 0; $x < count($result); $x++){
        //if attr array is empty push attribute into attr array
        //push spec data into spec array
        if($attrArray == []){
            array_push($attrArray,$result[$x]['attribute']);
            array_push($specArray,$result[$x]['specification']);
        }
        //check if attr array is not empty
        elseif($attrArray !== []){
            //count attr array length
            foreach($attrArray as $key){
                //push all spec data into spec array if have same next row attribute
                if($key == $result[$x]['attribute']){
                    array_push($specArray,$result[$x]['specification']);
                }
                //if next attribute is not same from previous attribute
                //push attr array into data array as key and spec array as value
                //empty attr and spec array and push new attr and spec data into array
                elseif($key !== $result[$x]['attribute']){
                    $dataArray[$key] = $specArray;
                    $attrArray = [];
                    $specArray = [];
                    array_push($attrArray,$result[$x]['attribute']);
                    array_push($specArray,$result[$x]['specification']);
                    //unset($key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print_r(json_encode($dataArray));
```

result:

```
{
    "Paper Material":["Gloss Art Card 250 gsm","Gloss Art Card 310 gsm","Gloss Art Card 360 gsm","Briliant White 220 gsm","Linen 240 gsm","Metal Ice 250 gsm","Synthetic Paper 180 micron","Super White 250 gsm","Suwen 240 gsm","Vellum 220 gsm","Frosted Plastic Card 0.4mm"],
    "Type":["Standard Business Card","Folded Business Card","Custom Die-Cut Business Card"],
    "Size":["54mm x 89mm","52mm x 86mm","50mm x 89mm","54mm x 86mm"], 
    "Orientation":["Portrait","Landscape"],
    "Lamination":["Not Required","Matte 2 Side","Matte 1 Side","Gloss 2 Side","Gloss 1 Side","Gloss Water Based Varnish 2 Side","Matte 2 Side + Spot UV 2 Side","Matte 2 Side + Spot UV 1 Side"],
    "Hot Stamping":["Not Required"],
    "Round Corner":["Not Required"],
    "Hole Punching":["Not Required"]
}
```

Where last attribute color is missing from the new array that i already created.

Please advise thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your issue:

You assign the `$dataArray[$key] = $specArray;` only when encounter a key that was not before as your comment said `//if next attribute is not same from previous attribute` (and then you reset your array and start counting for the new one)

The last key, `color` in your case never gets to that `if` as he is the last so he never different from previous key so you never insert him to result array

I may be missing something but you can simplify it a lot by just doing:

```
foreach($result as $e) {
    $dataArray[$e["attribute"]][] = $e["specification"];
}
```

I think you better use this then the complex code you having.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/cASld)

Comment: thank you for the clarification and answer. Its help :)

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to do this as other Users have pointed. But if you want to specifically fix your code, you can do it by adding following line after the for loop has finished and before you print you array

```
.
.

for($x = 0; $x < count($result); $x++){
.
.
.
.
}//For Loop Finishes here

$dataArray[$key] = $specArray; //Add this Line. This will add your color keys to array.
print_r(json_encode($dataArray));
```

Comment: Nice work finding the problem. I didn't have the patience to read an understand all that code for that "simple" of a task.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array and build the associative array based on the two items in the subarray.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($arr as $item){
    $new[$item["attribute"]][] = $item["specification"];
}

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/25Tvv

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple if you use [**array_reduce()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).

```
$data = array_reduce($data, function ($old, $new) {
    $old[$new->attribute] = isset($old[$new->attribute]) ? array_merge($old[$new->attribute], [$new->specification]) : [$new->specification];
    return $old;
}, []);

echo '<pre>', json_encode($data);
```

Working [**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/8hSgR).